# Android Debug: Frame is not available

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am trying to debug my android app. 
But every time in a specific point the debugger stops 
and closes the app without a dialog.

Running the app normally without debugging is without problems 
and the app runs the code the way it has to.

Have I to do some different setup to my debugger or do I miss something else?

[image]

Comment: No. I got the same problem.

Comment: I keep getting the same thing... Bounty time?

Comment: For me, most of the time is that I have touched the USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    ...
}